# How to get first packet of data using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

A program is streaming 2 things: a video and a KLV data.I am in a situation where running ffmpeg should get me first frame of image and first packet/frame of data also.I am able to get first frame as soon as i run ffmpeg command,now i want to get corresponding data packet/data.

Comment: From command line or your own program? Little information here you're giving.

Comment: i am running commands using a seperate process..so the commands will be similar to command lines